# Windows 8.1 Dism can't find source even when ISO mounted

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, dism

I had problems with my PC and I downloaded the ISO file for Win 8.1, because DISM wasn't working. Then I realized that I don't have install.wim file and I converted the install.esd file to install.wim(with ESDfileconverter) and copied it to the ISO and now in sources folder(on the ISO) I have both install.esd and install.wim and I tried again I mounted the ISO with Deamon Tools and wrote the command

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:WIM:F:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`

And after I ran it, it again gave me the same error 0x800f081f The source files could not be found. It is mounted on BD-ROM Drive(F:), so I guess my command is right? Also I am sure the conversion is ok?
Is there anyone that can help or just know what is the problem.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I had a similar problem. Assuming you have 8.1 Update 1 installed (KB2919355), you may need an ISO that has the KB2919355 files included. Because the files in the install.wim are older than your system files. Also to mount an ISO in Windows 8, just double click it. I don't have a good source for the ISO with Update 1

Comment: copy the folder C:\windows\logs to your desktop, compress it as zip/7z, upload it to your OneDrive and post a link here. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ihqx2rkD9dalZmTmw4c0lLYkk)

Comment: I also need the CBS folder, that's why I wanted the entire log folder.

Comment: @magicandre1981 [here the whole folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ihqx2rkD9dbnBzSEtQZDYtdmM)

Comment: ok, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows fails to find the 64Bit file `Windows.UI.Xaml.dll` in version `6.3.9600.16438`, `6.3.9600.16476` and `6.3.9600.16408`.

```
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-directui_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16438_none_a7ee6661c260dcb5\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-directui_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16476_none_a7c1261dc28319cb\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-directui_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16408_none_a80ed625c24888e2\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
```

`Windows.UI.Xaml.dll` in version `6.3.9600.16408` was part of the [GA update for Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2883200).

`Windows.UI.Xaml.dll` in version `6.3.9600.16438` was part of the [November 2013 update rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2887595).

`Windows.UI.Xaml.dll` in version `6.3.9600.16476` was part of the [January 2014 update rollup for Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2911106)

Also 3 CAT files are missing from KB2929825:

```
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_1_for_KB2929825~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_for_KB2929825_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0
(p) CBS Catalog Missing         Package_for_KB2929825~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0
```

Download the Update [KB2929825](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41693) and [integrate all 4 updates into the Install.wim with DISM](http://woshub.com/integrate-windows-updates-into-windows-8-image/).

After you unmounted/commited the changes, you can use DISM and point to the new updates WIM.

Comment: nice to hear this :)