# Windows 10 DISM cannot find files, even with ISO mounted

Tags: windows, dism, sfc

After running `sfc /SCANNOW` in my Windows 10 Pro installation, and getting

> "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix
>   some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log
>   windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log."

I tried to follow the steps here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93

and here http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html

After having created the Windows 10 ISO using the Media Creation Tool and running this command:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:G:\sources\install.esd:1` (I have tried to include `/LimitAccess` to no avail)

I am still getting errors,

> "Error: 0x800f081f
>
> The source files could not be found. Use the "Source" option to
>   specify the location of the files that are required to restore the
>   feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077."

I have tried to reboot, but it is still not fixing anything. (Of course, these commands are being run as administrator).

I could upload the DISM.log file if necessary.
The only similar question I could find was this one [Windows 8.1 Dism can't find source even when ISO mounted](https://superuser.com/questions/936836/windows-8-1-dism-cant-find-source-even-when-iso-mounted) but it refers to a Windows 8 problem and the updates that are suggested are specific to that OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved it. As I could find out here [Windows 10 DISM error: 0x800f081f](https://superuser.com/questions/951538/windows-10-dism-error-0x800f081f) the ISO created by the Windows 10 Media Creation tool does **not** work with DISM. I downloaded one from Techbench and managed to use DISM with that one.

I do not know whether it is the fact that the ISO created by the Tool has an ESD file instead of a WIM one, but changing the ISO to the Techbench one (which uses a WIM file instead) and using the adapted command 
`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:WIM:G:\sources\install.wim:1` did the trick

I cannot accept my own answer for 2 days, so will have to wait to mark this as answered

Comment: DISM documentation only mentions working with .wim or .vhd(x). I believe an ESD is an encrypted wim.

Comment: On the second link I included, it was mentioned that an ESD can be used, but I'm not sure. There are people asking how to convert an ESD to a WIM. But well, I suppose you are correct since using an ISO file with a WIM file instead worked great!

Comment: Old thread that bubbled up, but it may have been that the original attempt used the wrong index. If I recall correctly, on the ISO Windows Pro is maybe index 8. Index 1 is the locked down Windows 10 S. DISM can query the indices of the image.

Answer (score 5):

So, I was having the same problem, and I was able to solve it using the following method.
I downloaded the Windows Image (ISO) using the [Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Therefore, I did not want to download another image using a third party website.

To solve this, try following these steps.

- [Download the Windows Image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- Extract it to a Local Drive. (For example E:/)
- Make sure it has all the necessary permissions.
- Make sure your command is correct. (E.g.: Drive Letter, Index number, etc)
- Try it now.

If it doesn't work, create a new administrator account and try again.

---

Commands:

- `SFC /SCANNOW`
- `DISM /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:G:\WinISO\sources\install.wim`
- `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:X:\WinISO\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`

[image: Screenshot]

To check the index number, run this command.
`DISM /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:X:\WinISO\sources\install.wim`
( '`X:\WinISO\sources\install.wim`' - This should be replaced)

If you are not certain about the commands, please check these websites.

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system
- https://www.wintips.org/fix-dism-source-files-could-not-be-found-windows-10-8/
- [Windows 10 DISM error: 0x800f081f](https://superuser.com/q/951538/485660)

---

Download Microsoft Windows:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO

If you are having trouble downloading Windows ISO from Microsoft website, please refer to these websites:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/427223/how-to-download-a-windows-10-iso-without-the-media-creation-tool/
- https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-download-iso/

Comment: Note that this link "[Download the Windows Image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)" leads to different pages. Clicking this from my pc will open a page forcing me to download the media creation tool. But when I use my phone it opens a page allowing me to download the .iso directly which is what I think you had intended with your answer. Thanks Microsoft. 

Comment: Update: it turns out that on my phone I was logged in with a Microsoft account from work.

Comment: @Mr.Z. TY. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With this instruction you can convert esd to wim without downloading with external dangerous links:

dism /export-image /SourceImageFile:install.esd /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:install.wim /Compress:max /CheckIntegrity

Check with this what index:

dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:install.esd

Source:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/163540-convert-esd-to-wim