# How to execute DISM from Windows 10 PE on Win 10 system with Windows Update / Microsoft as source only?

Tags: windows-10, dism, bootrepair, sfc

I've got a corrupt Windows 10 installation (SFC noted `Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix someo of them`...) so I tried to run DISM, from a Windows 10 PE USB installation. (Note: Win10 PE current OS is at `c:` and offline system on system is at `i:`)

Here's what happened:
#1:

```
c:\Windows\system32>dism /image:i:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 6.3.9600.18384

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

So then I wrote Windows 10 2004 iso (via Rufus) to a USB so that I've have an `install.esd` in place to see how that might work, but it likewise failed:
#2:

```
C:\Windows\system32>dism /image:i:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:esd:K:\sources\install.esd:1

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 6.3.9600.18384

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

How can I guarantee that `DISM` pulls all appropriate files from Microsoft to repair an image (Windows installation) with the correct version, etc?

UPDATE: On #1 I was hoping that DISM would pull in the appropriate image files via Windows Update, but perhaps it doesn't and thus I tried #2.  On #2 it was suggested that you must have a matching .esd or .wim file, so I found an old copy of `Windows 10 Version 1903` I had previously floating around and put that onto a flash drive via Rufus.  I then attempted to execute DISM again with that, but met with failure likewise, but this time also captured the dism.log output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>dism /image:i:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:wim:K:\sources\install.wim:1

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 6.3.9600.18384

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

The log output can be found here [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/a889aaebe40892dc1ddd106c49e91302).

With the 1st error I noted in the `dism.log`, being the following:

```
2020-06-19 18:17:35, Error                 CBS    Cannot add wim: file source because it is not supported during offline servicing [HRESULT = 0x800f082e - CBS_E_NOT_ALLOWED_OFFLINE]
```

I figured I should try mounting the `install.wim` via:

```
K:
cd sources
K:\sources>mkdir c:\mount
K:\sources>dism /mount-wim /wimfile:install.wim /index:1 /mountdir:c:\mount
```

And then I tried to run dism again:

```
dism /image:i:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:c:\mount

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 6.3.9600.18384

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Notice errors began to appear around line 253 here in the new dism.log, but I'm not sure why since I'm using a mount wim now:
[dism.log gist](https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/90ea6391d562fc879d9c7bdee59b0806)

Comment: You can’t use a 2004 ISO to repair a 1903 installation

Comment: I appreciate your noting this. What my original thought was and thus the title of my question: how can I use DISM to use an image from Microsoft?  I was thinking that in the original command (`dism /image:i:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth `) that it would pull the 1903 image from MS for repair... but no?

Comment: Sometimes, it's easier to reinstall from ISO, keeping files... if you can get a Windows 1903 ISO.

Comment: @ylluminate - Why were you indicating the source was on that drive letter?  That is the reason you got the error while within Windows.  As for the error within WinPE that is due to one the syntax being incorrect but also the source data was incorrect. The bottom line is you can't use a 2004 ISO to repair 1903.  The relevant information from `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log` is required to answer this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1033914/windows-10-dism-cannot-find-files-even-with-iso-mounted) question.

Comment: @Ramhound I've used the suggested 1903 iso and also had an error and attached the log.

Comment: @Ramhound added another update, you see any hints as to what's going on here?